# How to implement zod on dynamic fields?

Tags: typescript, zod

I have this interface before

```
export interface SomeData {
  data: string
  [step_: `step_${string}`]: string
  [retry_: `retry_${string}`]: string
  [count_: `count_${string}`]: string
}
```

And I want to implement a zod schema based on this interface.
I'm not sure how to do this on the dynamic fields. The following is not accepted by typescript.

```
export const SomeDataSchema = z.object({
  data: z.string(),
  [step_: `step_${string}`]: z.string(),
  [retry_: `retry_${string}`]: z.string(),
  [count_: `count_${string}`]: z.string()
})
```

A sample payload may contain something like this:

```
{
  data: 'some data',
  step_1: 'some data',
  step_2: 'some data',
  count_1: 'some data'
}
```

How do I resolve this?

I am expecting something that can still contain templated field names.

Comment: Make a custom validator

Comment: @vr Can you show me how it's done?

Answer (score 1):

This was mentioned in a comment, but zod provides a `custom` validator for validating template string types: [see the docs](https://github.com/colinhacks/zod#custom-schemas)

An example of a schema that would be able to parse your data with *reasonable* types is:

```js
import { z } from 'zod';

const schema = z.record(
  z.union([
    z.literal('data'),
    z.custom<`step_${string}`>((val) => {
      return /step_.+/.test(val as string);
    }),
    z.custom<`count_${string}`>((val) => {
      return /count_.+/.test(val as string);
    }),
    z.custom<`retry_${string}`>((val) => {
      return /retry_.+/.test(val as string);
    }),
  ]),
  z.string(),
);
```

The main drawback is that the `data` field may not be defined in the resulting value. It might make sense to parse the data out separately?

Comment: And what should be done in case `data` field needs to be an object type?

Comment: Now you’re getting into more complicated territory. You need to either parse in stages (first parse with `unknown` values, then pull out the `data` field, and finally parse the remaining fields) or you’ll need to make your own schema for parsing records that ignores keys that don’t match your pattern. I think I’m either case your drifting into new territory so it might be worth asking a separate question